# What's the need for call() in prototypical inheritance

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

I'm having some trouble deciphering prototypical inheritance in JavaScript, and thought of posting it here. Consider this simple example:

```
function Employee() {
    this.name = "Rob";
    this.dept = "R&D";
}

function Manager() {
    //Employee.call(this);
    this.reports = ["Report 1", "Report 2", "Report 3"];
}

Manager.prototype = Object.create(Employee.prototype);

Employee.prototype.type = "human";
m = new Manager();
console.log(m.name); //undefined
console.log(m.type); //human
```

What I can't understand is the utility of the line `Employee.call(this)`. Since we're going to be setting Employee.protoype as Manager's prototype, what's the need for (as I see it) explicitly forcing the creation of variables in Employee through `call()`? Earlier I thought that it might be because no object of `Employee` exists, and JS inheritance can't work without objects, so `call()` here served to "complete the object build". But then, the `type` property gets reflected in Manager without the need for `call()`, which proves that we don't need a hard object to perform inheritance (what I mean is, just the class-like constructor function definition will do).

I hope I haven't made it too complicated. In short: Why is `call()` needed here, and why does the property `type` work without `call()` (if `call()` is that important, that is).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of `Employee.call(this)` is to add name and department attributes to Manager instances.

Usage of `call()` is more by convention and it allows to modify the caller (this) in place.

The property `type` worked since you went through the prototype interface.

If you uncomment the `Employee.call(this)`, then m.name will become 'Rob'.

Comment: "The purpose of Employee.call(this) is to add name and department attributes to Manager instances." Then what is `Manager.prototype = Object.create(Employee.prototype);` doing? Why doesn't it lead to inheriting those values? "Usage of call() is more by convention and it allows to modify the caller (this) in place." I know what, but why is it needed? In inheritance, we're talking about classes and blueprints (I hope) not objects. Maybe what I'm asking is more on the lines of language design philosophy, but some in-depth answers would be more helpful.

Comment: The Object.create() only copies over the prototypes. The name and dept properties aren't in the prototype but in the constructor, hence they aren't automatically copied. If you'd go Manager.prototype = Object.create(Employee) then 'name' and 'dept' would get copied as well, but the usage of call to do this is more widespread.

Comment: @dotslash as a matter of fact, there are no classes in JavaScript (even if EcmaScript 6 might make you believe so). There are only Objects that delegate to other objects. Working with the `new` operator just fakes a pseudo-classical inheritance. But it's not how javascript works on the inside. The following post by Eric Elliott might help to clear things up: https://medium.com/javascript-scene/common-misconceptions-about-inheritance-in-javascript-d5d9bab29b0a

Comment: @nils Honestly, JavaScript feels like getting into a rabbit hole! Thanks for the help. Will check out the link.

Comment: @dotslash yes, I know that feeling all too well ;) If you want a more in-depth explanation, check out Kyle Simpsons' book (its free on github): https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes
It helped me clear up a lot of misunderstandings I had.

Comment: @Shilly Wow! Now that was a true insight for me. I was thinking of prototype and constructor as one (I reasoned that the blueprint of an object must have every property the object has).

Comment: Really short answer: Employee.prototype doesn't contain any "name" property. And it's Employee.prototype you use when creating Manager, not an object constructed by calling Employee.

Comment: @dotslash as Shilly mentioned, the prototypes are only copied by the code you mentioned in comments. This is difficult to wrap around ones head, but my answer really described what happens by using .call(this).

Comment: @ChristianMICHON "the prototypes are only copied by the code you mentioned in comments. " Seriously?! OMG, when will this confusion called JavaScript end? :D

Comment: @ChristianMICHON So you mean to say `Employee.call(this)` copies the prototype for the current object, while `Manager.prototype = Object.create(Employee.prototype);` pushes it into the prototype chain for all future objects? If yes, I think yours was a superb answer and I'll proceed to accept it post-haste.

Comment: @dotslash in essence yes... Thanks for the kudos

Comment: @nils More than three months have gone by. I took your advice and read You Don't Know JS. Today, I am enlightened and can't thank you enough! You made my life. :-)

Comment: @dotslash I'm glad you enjoyed them, they also helped me tremendously :)

Answer (score 1):

Even though the prototype is inherited, which is where the type 'human' is defined, without the call to Employee you aren't "initializing the base class" and running the code inside the `Employee()` constructor. Just because Employee is the prototype of Manager doesn't guarantee you want to run the Employee constructor when you create a manager.

Unlike some languages where you can call `super()`, you have to call the initializer for the base class by name. This is similar to C++:

```
class Manager : public Employee {
public:
    Manager() : Employee() {}
};
```

You also get to decide when to call the parent and perform additional logic, where an automatic call wouldn't give you that option:

```
function Employee(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.dept = "R&D";
}

function Manager(name) {
    // Add the title to the name, first
    var mgrName = name + ' (Manager)';

    Employee.call(this, mgrName);
    this.reports = ["Report 1", "Report 2", "Report 3"];
}

Manager.prototype = Object.create(Employee.prototype);
m = new Manager('Bill');
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.type` (and other prototypically inherited properties) do work, yes.
But `.name` and `.dept` don't, they were not created on `m`! You were quite right, the `Employee.call(this)` is required for a *complete initialisation*. It's the `super` call of the constructor, which you shouldn't omit.